# Apache Flume - incorrect timestamp

Tags: hadoop, flume

When I use Apache Flume, I get a millisecond timestamp rahter then a second timestamp.
This is my flume conf file:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
a1.sources.r1.port = 44444

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = flume/ads/%y-%m-%d/%H
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 10000

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Flume creates folder flume/ads/70-01-17/02. The folder contains files "FlumeData.timestamp" and this timestamp has twelve digits.

I get an incorrect folder's name.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

In section Sink should be:

```
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = True
```